# Correct way to send image on body phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I found various question about that here, but i cant found my mistake.

In my site i have image logo with that path(by inspector browser):

```
src="/img/header_logo.png"
```

So on phpMailer seting i do:

```
[...]
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                 
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("/img/header_logo.png", "my-attach", "image/png");
$mail->Body = '<img alt="PHPMailer" src="cid:my-attach">';
[...]
```

But img dont work. Any tips?

Comment: Your image path may be wrong. What you wrote `/img/header_logo.png` means that the script should load it from the filesystem root, i guess you have to refer from relative path (starting from the script). So check the path.

Comment: ok i solved using '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].`...tks